Picard group of coordinate axes
What is the Picard group of the coordinate axes $X = \text{Spec }k[x,y]/(xy)$?
Using this, it is clear that the answer is $k^\times$, resolving the curve $X$ by the disjoint union of two affine lines $\widetilde{X}$.
However, consider the LES for cohomology of $1 \rightarrow O_X^\times \rightarrow \pi_* O_{\widetilde{X}}^\times \rightarrow \pi_*  O_{\widetilde{X}}^\times/O_X^\times \rightarrow 1$, whose third term appears to be a skyscraper at the origin with value $k^\times$. (This is asserted for an irreducible proper semistable nodal curve, in Example 8 in Chapter 9 of BLR, but as it's a local problem about nodes I don't see why the global hypotheses would be necessary.) That would seem to imply that $Pic(X) = 0$ instead.

Your first link doesn't apply to the situation at hand - Hartshorne II.6.9 assumes the curve is integral projective, while your $X$ is neither. (And in fact these assumptions are necessary - we need $\mathcal{O}_X(X)=k$ in the linked proof.)

Projective yes. Why do you say Hartshorne assume the curve is integral? I don't have the book at the moment, but this isn't in the linked copy of the question. (I think that's the more pertinent issue for me.)

Hartshorne uses the word "curve" in chapter II to refer to a one-dimensional integral separated scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field. See remark II.4.10.1.

As KReiser pointed out, your first approach to calculate this is incorrect as you are missing necessary hypotheses. Since you’re reading BLR, I will assume that you have more advanced knowledge than Hartshorne. In particular, I think the following correct calculation might be of interest to you.
Set

$U_x=\mathrm{Spec}(k[x^{\pm 1}])$,
$U_y=\mathrm{Spec}(k[y^{\pm 1}])$,
and $\widehat{V}=\mathrm{Spec}(k[\![x,y]\!]/(xy))$.

Then, $\mathcal{U}=\{U_x,U_y,\widehat{V}\}$ is an fpqc cover of $X$. Now, $H^1(X_\mathrm{Zar},\mathbb{G}_m)=H^1(X_\mathrm{fpqc},\mathbb{G}_m)$ (by ‘Hilbert’s Theorem 90’, i.e., fpqc descent for quasi-coherent sheaves). But, observe that
$$\mathrm{Pic}(U_x)=\mathrm{Pic}(U_y)=\mathrm{Piv}(\widehat{V})=0.$$
The first two Picard groups vanishing is that $U_x$ and $U_y$ are spectra of PIDs, and the last is because $\widehat{V}$ is local. So, by Tag 0A6G, we see that
$$\mathrm{Pic}(X)\simeq \check{H}^1(\mathcal{U},\mathbb{G}_m).$$
But, this latter Čech cohomology group is zero. Namely, one has that
$$\mathbb{G}_m(U_x)=k^\times\cdot x^{\mathbb{Z}},\quad \mathbb{G}_m(U_y)=k^\times\cdot y^\mathbb{Z},\quad \mathbb{G}_m(\widehat{V})=k^\times.$$
Evidently the only way for a triple $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ in $\mathbb{G}_m(U_x)\times\mathbb{G}_m(U_y)\times\mathbb{G}_m(\widehat{V})$ to agree on all overlaps is if it is in the diagonally embedded copy of $k^\times$. But, this is the same as the image of $\mathbb{G}_m(X)$ in $\mathbb{G}_m(U_x)\times\mathbb{G}_m(U_y)\times\mathbb{G}_m(\widehat{V})$, so this Čech cohomolgy is indeed zero.
